# Content Porter: Changing client/server timeouts DB isues

Tags: 2013, content-porter-2013

I'm trying to import a bundle containing components, but I'm always getting ORA errors. Our dba suggested we change the timeout because maybe the procedure takes longer than the configured timeouts.

For the client I found the file `system.servicemodel.bindings.config.deploy` and the timeouts are set 30 minutes. Where is the server core service cons located?

> ORA:01013 USER REQUESTED CANCEL OF CURRENT OPERATION  [Error]
>   Tridion.ContentManager.DatabaseException: A database error occurred
>   while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_ORG_ITEMS.READ_ORG_ITEM". --->
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-03113: end-of-file on
>   communication channel

Answer (score 1):

This ORA issue happens when a connection is open for long time. Previously we have also faced the same type of issue in 2011 SP1. To resolve this issue permanently you have to raise a ticket with SDL support team and they will provide you the hotfix for that.

But as a workaround you can try below process which help to resolve the issue in our case -

1) If you a lot of items in the bundle then I would suggest to break it into 2-3 bundles(smaller in size). 
2) Restart the tridion services and then try to port it again.

But again this is a workaround not a permanent solution.

Answer (score 1):

Open a support ticket with SDL for this issue. They can provide you documentation on all the settings to adjust for your situation.

We have used this documentation to implement content porter with good success.